# Formula Help - Change in Business Activities by Month

Tags: community, formula

I have a custom object that track business activities each month.  I'd like to create a exception report that only shows change in activities (-15% or less) month over month.  Example

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s197/sh/c2a49c7e-2ee8-41f6-8a2b-e69e7937b0e8/e275f67de50fbc1792544660c177dacf

I'm thinking of a custom formula field on this object that calculate the percentage change in activities.  How would I write that formula?  Is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks,

-Dan

Answer (score 0):

Formula fields can only reference fields on the same record or on records to which they have a lookup/master-detail relationship.

You add a lookup field on your custom activity to the previous month's record, and then write the formula field like this:

```
IF(
  ISBLANK(PM_Sales_Activity__c),
  1,
  (Activity__c - PM_Sales_Activity__r.Activity__c) / PM_Sales_Activity__r.Activity__c
)
```

In my example, PM_Sales_Activity__c is the lookup to the previous month's Sales Activity record for the same customer. (If the lookup field was blank, the percent change is 100%.) So if last month Activity__c was 10 and this month it's 15, the percent change is +50%.

I don't think this is the most foolproof way of solving this, as it hinges on the lookup field being set correctly, which -- if set manually -- could easily introduce errors. It would probably be safer to use a trigger to update the Percentage Change field and make it a read-only percentage field.